# C++ range-based for loop and copy of element

Tags: c++

I want to generate all subsets of a given vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> findSubsets(const vector<int> &nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> subsets;
        subsets.push_back(vector<int>{}); //empty set
        for (auto current_num : nums)
        {
            //add current_num to all existing subsets
            int n = subsets.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                vector<int> set(subsets[i]);
                set.push_back(num);
                subsets.push_back(set);
            }
        }
        return subsets;
    }
```

I wanted to use a range based for loop for iterating over all subsets it gives a different result:

```
vector<vector<int>> findSubsets(const vector<int> &nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> subsets;
        subsets.push_back(vector<int>{}); //empty set
        for (auto current_num : nums)
        {
            //add current_num to all existing subsets
            for (vector<int> subset : subsets)
            {
                subset.push_back(current_num);
                subsets.push_back(subset);
            }
        }
        return subsets;
    }
```

But this does not do what I intended. What am I missing?

Comment: `for (... : subsets) { subsets.push_back(...); }` - you can't (shouldn't) do that. Modifying the size of the container invalidates the `end` iterator, which is obtained first when expanding range-based `for`. Comparing an iterator (which range-based for internally does) with an invalid `end()` iterator is, I believe, undefined behaviour. No surprise that you get different results when you invoke or not invoke UB.

Comment: Don't modify the container you are iterating in a range based loop.

Comment: @Fureeish why didn't you post it as an answer so it could be accepted and close the question?

Comment: @passing_through because I am on mobile and I don't like to create answers which are of a mediocre quality, and creating a good quality answer on mobile would take too much time. Feel free to adapt my comment and post an answer. If you decide not to do so, I will create an answer when I get back home, i.e., in about 3 to 5 hours.

Comment: Your first version does not compile. I think you meant `set.push_back(current_num)` instead of `set.push_back(num)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @Fureeish one problem with the second version is inserting to the subsets vector while iterating over the subsets vector.

```
for (vector<int> subset : subsets)
 {
   subset.push_back(current_num);
   subsets.push_back(subset);  // Should not modify vector while iterating on it
 }
```

The range statement expands to something like:

```
{

    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {

        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

The __end expression is expanded before the iterations. For a vector this could be calculating the address at vector.data[size]. If the loop pushes new elements into the vector, the __end expression is no longer correct.

If you iterated over a copy of the vector instead, the range statement would work. For example:

```
    for (vector<int> subset : vector<vector<int>>(subsets))
    {
        subset.push_back(current_num);
        subsets.push_back(subset);
    }
```